# edebug-defun indicates a malformed cl-loop

Tags: edebug

The following code evaluates successfully using `eval-defun` and runs as I would expect:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(defun my/sample-function ()
  (let ((my-ht (make-hash-table)))
    (puthash :a 1 my-ht)
    (puthash :b 2 my-ht)
    (cl-loop for key being the hash-keys of my-ht using (hash-values value)
             do
             (prin1 (cons key value)))))
```

with

```
(my/sample-function)
=> (:a . 1)(:b . 2)nil
```

However, `edebug-defun` complains:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Bad ‘using’ clause")                 
  signal(error ("Bad ‘using’ clause"))                                     
  error("Bad `using' clause")                                              
  cl--parse-loop-clause()                                                  
  #[128 "\306\307\310\311\312\311\306\313!\"\"\">\204\314\312\315\3...
  macroexpand((cl-loop for key being the hash-keys of my-ht using (edebug-a...
  macroexp-macroexpand((cl-loop for key being the hash-keys of my-ht using ...
  macroexp--expand-all((cl-loop for key being the hash-keys of my-ht using ...
  ...
```

I imagine that edebug is choking during instrumentation on the hash-table -specific parts of the complex `cl-loop` macro.  This is the first time I've encountered this sort of problem with edebug.

I'm not certain that this is not the result of user-error though. In Common Lisp documentation the keywords appear singular with a different verb ordering ([example source](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/doc/cl/loop.html)):

```
(loop for k being the hash-key using (hash-value v) of h do ...
```

However, the structure used within `my/sample-function` above is the only form I have found to eval successfully.

I couldn't find anything relevant in debbugs.

emacs -Q version 25.1.1

Comment: [#24750](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24750) I think

Comment: @npostavs I agree.  I can confirm that my problem is fixed in 26.  Add as an answer and I'll close this Q; thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Emacs Bug#24750](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24750), which is fixed in the `master` branch (what will become 26.1).  For earlier versions, you can add `["using" (symbolp symbolp)]` to `cl-loop`'s edebug spec.

```el
(put 'cl-loop 'edebug-form-spec
     '(&rest &or
             [[&or "for" "as" "with" "and"]
              sexp]
             [[&or "from" "upfrom" "downfrom" "to" "upto" "downto" "above" "below" "by" "in" "on" "=" "across" "repeat" "while" "until" "always" "never" "thereis" "collect" "append" "nconc" "sum" "count" "maximize" "minimize" "if" "unless" "return"]
              form]
             ["using" (symbolp symbolp)]
             symbolp form))
```